# In an XML with 2 or more namespace declaration, is it possible to reference to xpaths dynamically if namespace prefix changes in the future

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0, xml-namespaces, xslt-3.0

I'm working on some xsl development. The XML being transformed has 2 namespaces. One has a prefix of ns2 `xmlns:ns2="http://xmlns.example.com/eventNotify/v1"`.

The other, is the default : `xmlns="http://xmlns.example.com/cds/customer"`

Suppose we have this xml that has 2 namespaces

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ns2:accountEventNotify xmlns:ns2="http://xmlns.example.com/eventNotify/v1" xmlns="http://xmlns.example.com/cds/customer" schemaVersion="1">
   <ns2:header>
      <ns2:employee>
         <ns2:opco>ABCD</ns2:opco>
         <ns2:number>1111111</ns2:number>
      </ns2:employee>
      <ns2:sourceSystem>SYS1</ns2:sourceSystem>
      <ns2:msgCreateTime>2022-06-15T16:58:30.599Z</ns2:msgCreateTime>
      <ns2:businessEvent>
         <ns2:event>maintenance</ns2:event>
      </ns2:businessEvent>
   </ns2:header>
   <ns2:accountNumber>123456789</ns2:accountNumber>
   <ns2:messageType>CREATE</ns2:messageType>
   <ns2:create>
      <enterpriseProfile domain="customer" majorVersion="0" minorVersion="30">
         <accountNumber>123456789</accountNumber>
         <profile>
            <customerType>AAA</customerType>
            <accountType>AAA</accountType>
            <accountStatus>
               <statusCode>ACTIVE</statusCode>
               <statusDate>2022-06-15</statusDate>
            </accountStatus>
            <creationDate>2022-06-15</creationDate>
            <originSource>FF</originSource>
            <accountLinkageFlag>false</accountLinkageFlag>
            <welcomeKit>
               <welcomeKitFlag>false</welcomeKitFlag>
            </welcomeKit>
         </profile>
      </enterpriseProfile>     
   </ns2:create>
</ns2:accountEventNotify>
```

For example, if I want to exclude the parent node `<ns2:create>` and its child nodes, I can simply write `<xsl:template match="ns2:create" />` which is fine.

There are two possible future scenarios in the system I'm working on :

1. What if the **ns2** prefix somehow changed to **abc** or something else?

   That scenario will break reference(s) to existing xpath(s) in xsl file. Example is
   `<xsl:template match="ns2:create" />` must change to `<xsl:template match="abc:create" />`
2. What if namespace value got change inversely / opposite?

   **FROM :**

   `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> <ns2:accountEventNotify xmlns:ns2="http://xmlns.example.com/eventNotify/v1" xmlns="http://xmlns.example.com/cds/customer" schemaVersion="1">`

   **TO :**

   `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> <ns2:accountEventNotify xmlns:ns2="http://xmlns.example.com/cds/customer" xmlns="http://xmlns.example.com/eventNotify/v1" schemaVersion="1">`

My worry is the possibility of the code breaking in the future.
Currently, the source of the XML I am transforming is generating namespace values inconsistently (Like in scenario 2 above).

How to handle the 2 scenarios above? Should I write 2 separate XSL scripts?
What if ns2 changes to abc in the future?

I'd appreciate any advice.

Thank you.

Comment: The prefix your input XML uses is not important at all. What matters is the URI bound to the prefix. As long as that does not change, your stylesheet can continue to function using its own prefix (or no prefix by defining a default namespace). If the URI *can* change, as shown in your 2nd scenario, than that's a different story altogether. If you don't know the exact schema of the input XML, then your stylesheet has to take some risks. The presumption is that different namespaces are there to distinguish between different nodes - therefore ignoring the namespaces may lead to unwanted matches.

Comment: Thanks for the very useful info and comment @michael.hor257k. Actually, I am now facing the 2nd scenario. During initial development, the client didn't show me that there is another xml variant that has a different URI.
If you are suggesting that ignoring namespaces isn't recommended, then should I just create 2 separate XSL's to handle and accommodate Scenario 2?

Comment: If there are 2 possible namespaces, you can accommodate them both by declaring them using 2 different prefixes, then matching/selecting using the union operator - for example: `<xsl:template match="ns1:create | ns2:create" />`. However, this assumes that only one of the two namespaces will be used in each instance. Otherwise you again expose yourself to the risk of a false positive match.

Answer (score 1):

Let's assume you've defined a `ns1` namespace prefix for the default namespace, for clarity of reference.  Then here are two options:

1. **Match anticipated namespaces<sup>1</sup>:**

   ```
   <xsl:template match="ns1:create | ns2:create" />
   ```
2. **Ignore namespaces:**

   XSLT 1.0+

   ```
   <xsl:template match="*[local-name() = 'create']" />
   ```

   XSLT 2.0+

   ```
   <xsl:template match="*:create" />
   ```

Remember that changing namespaces is equivalent to changing names.  Do not expect general robustness in the face of such changes.  If `create` is changed to `destroy`, there's likely an associated semantic difference, and your code cannot be expected to deal with such changes without an update.  Similarly, `create` in one namespace may have different semantics than `create` in a different namespace.

---

<sub>1. Thanks to @michael.hor257k for a simplifying suggestion for form #1.</sub>

Comment: Thanks for the answer. For that approach, does it require that I define `ns1` for the default namespace?

Comment: Not in your input XML, no.  For your XSLT, I believe you'll find your code easier to read if you do define an explicit namespace, but see also `xpath-default-namespace` for XSLT 2.0 and up.

Comment: @michael.hor257k: Yes, you're right.  Answer updated.  Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to handle two variant vocabularies that differ primarily in the choice of namespace URI, then my preferred approach is to create a pipeline of two transformations: the first normalizes the namespace URI to the preferred form, and the second does the real work.

This gives you better separation of concerns, with simpler and more reusable code, and less chance of bugs through forgetting to handle both namespaces everywhere you use an element name.